# I try to sending Time and Date from rails mailer, but Time and Date not sending exactly

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, mailer

Here is my snippet from the view:

```
<tr >
  <td style="width:25%;font-weight:bold;border-bottom-width:1px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:rgb(235,235,235)">Appointment Date</td>
  <td style="width:50%;border-bottom-width:1px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:rgb(235,235,235)"><%= @appointment.apmnt_date.strftime('%B %m, %Y')%></td>
</tr>
<tr >
  <td style="width:25%;font-weight:bold;border-bottom-width:1px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:rgb(235,235,235)">Appointment Time</td>
  <td style="width:50%;border-bottom-width:1px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:rgb(235,235,235)"><%= @appointment.apmnt_date.strftime('%I:%M %p')%></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: have you used html.erb file extension?

Comment: In which date format apmnt_date is store in db?